# css change size affects by moving rest of the divs

Tags: css, size, move

Please if someone can help me solving the problem that grey box, when hovered, affects the yellow and the red boxes by moving them further down. I don't want that to happen, only the gray box to change its size.

Here is the code:
**HTML**

```
<div class="st"></div>
<div class="sot"></div>
<div class="sots"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.st {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.st:hover {
    height: 110px;
}
.sot {
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.sots {
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khqxd0mr/1/

Thank you for any solution,
CP

Comment: Use `calc` to calculate margin. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/khqxd0mr/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom: -10px` to `.st:hover` You are hacking the CSS box model to retain the position. `-10px` is relative to the extended height `110px`.

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/khqxd0mr/3/)

```css
.st {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.st:hover {
  height: 110px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
.sot {
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
 
}
.sots {
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="st"></div>
<div class="sot"></div>
<div class="sots"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I chose this answer as the correct one because it is the  most convenient approach.

Comment: No problem. Welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a transform

```css
.st {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:gray;
    transform-origin:center top;
}
.st:hover {
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
}
.sot {
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.sots {
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="st"></div>
<div class="sot"></div>
<div class="sots"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use this as an alternative due to browsers compatibilities.